Merge/Pivot Two Rows to One Row
Would like to ask how can I get this result?
Each id_item only has two rows of data. Need to merge same id_item rows to different column (IN and OUT), including date and qty.
My current data:



id_transaction
id_item
item_name
brand
type
qty
date




4
83
Glass Wine
XYZ
IN
100
2023-01-01


4
84
Plastic Cup
IKEA
IN
50
2023-01-01


5
83
Glass Wine
XYZ
OUT
10
2023-03-20



Expected result:



id_item
item_name
brand
IN
date
OUT
date




83
Glass Wine
XYZ
100
2023-01-01
10
2023-03-20


84
Plastic Cup
IKEA
50
2023-01-01
0
N/A




you need to add more details like which query you are running to get this data.

You need to explain the necessary logic required to obtain the expected result

Have a look at conditional aggregation; there are literally 100's (if not 1,000's) of examples.

I doubt this is really the intended result. And if so, I doubt anyone can work with it ;) Why should for example OUT be 0? In none of the rows, it is 0 and for example, 100 - 50 -10 are also not 0. Please explain detailed the logic behind.

sounds like he wants to merge "upcoming" row into the current one. although, the example data is kinda poor, what happens if there are some other rows. OP, you can read about LEAD function perhaps to get the next "row" in order and base your new columns in that.

data
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   id_transaction INTEGER  NOT NULL  
  ,id_item        INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,item_name      VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,brand          VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,type           VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,qty            INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,date           DATE  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable
(id_transaction,id_item,item_name,brand,type,qty,date) VALUES
(4,83,'Glass Wine','XYZ','IN',100,'2023-01-01'),
(4,84,'Plastic Cup','IKEA','IN',50,'2023-01-01'),
(5,83,'Glass Wine','XYZ','OUT',10,'2023-03-20'); 

don't usepivot,use case with max
select 
  id_item,
  item_name,
  brand,
  max(case when type='IN' then qty else 0 end)   as 'IN',
  max(case when type='IN'  then date end ) as 'Date',
  max(case when type='OUT' then qty else 0 end)   as 'OUT',
  max(case when type='OUT' then date   end)   as 'Date'
from mytable
group by id_item,
  item_name,
  brand

if interested in printing N/A,use
cast and Isnull
select 
  id_item,
  item_name,
  brand,
  max(case when type='IN' then qty else 0 end)   as 'IN',
  ISNULL(CAST(max(case when type='IN'  then date end ) AS VARCHAR(20)) ,'N/A') as 'Date',
  max(case when type='OUT' then qty else 0 end)   as 'OUT',
  ISNULL(CAST(MAX(case when type='OUT' then date end)  AS VARCHAR(20)),'N/A') as 'Date'
from mytable
group by id_item,
  item_name,
  brand

dbfiddle

thank you for your answer, but how do I get the OUT quantity as well?

That does not give the expected results

I used a PIVOT in a CTE - a bit long-winded but you can see what is going on (@tab is my table variable with your data in)
with PivotTheTable as
(
    select id_item,item_name,brand, [IN]
    , CASE WHEN [IN] IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE [date] END AS INDATE
    ,[OUT]
    , CASE WHEN [OUT] IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE [date] END AS OUTDATE
    from
    (
        select id_item,item_name,brand,[type],[date], qty
        from @tab
    ) anc
    PIVOT
    (
        sum(qty) for [type] in ([IN], [OUT])
    ) pvt1
)
select 
    id_item
    ,item_name
    ,brand
    ,SUM([IN]) as [IN]
    ,MAX(INDATE) AS INDATE
    ,SUM([OUT]) as [OUT]
    ,MAX(OUTDATE) AS OUTDATE
from PivotTheTable
group by id_item,item_name,brand

That returned
id_item item_name   brand   IN  INDATE      OUT     OUTDATE
83      Glass Wine  XYZ     100 2023-01-01  10      2023-03-20
84      Plastic Cup IKEA    50  2023-01-01  NULL    NULL

You can use ISNULL to cope with the NULL values - I've left that as an exercise.
